# Symfony2: isGranted for other entity

Tags: php, symfony, security, fosuserbundle

My application has the following hierarchy of roles:

> - ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN
>
>   - ROLE_ADMIN
>
>     - ROLE_USER

I have my controller that makes this work:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/delete/{id}", name="_admin_delete")
 * @Secure(roles="ROLE_ADMIN")
 */
public function deleteuserAction($id)
{
    $user = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserBy(array('id' => $id));
    if (null === $user) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('User id not found');
    }

    if ($user->hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        // You can not delete this user!
        throw new ...
    }

    // delete user
    $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager')->deleteUser($user);

    // ...
}
```

deleteuserAction is accessible to all those with ROLE_ADMIN.. but I want that they can not delete users who have the role `ROLE_ADMIN` or *HIGHER*.

There is a proper way to do this?

With this configuration you can delete `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`... yeah, you can add it to the list to block it, but with a complicated hierarchy can become difficult to manage.

Comment: Having any problem? your approach seems to be correct.

Comment: @Xocoatzin, with this configuration you can delete ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN...  yeah, you can add it to the list to block it, but with a complicated hierarchy can become difficult to manage.

Comment: Use Access control lists (http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/acl.html) if you want to have more complex ownership scenarios on your app.

Comment: I'd say he doesn't need ACLs here. Voters should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use ACLs, another option would be to create a custom voter that handles your hierarchy. A basic voter is described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html